# Opencv does not read file in a different directory

Tags: python, opencv, unicode, path

I get an error like down below:

```
[ WARN:0@23.978] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp (239) cv::findDecoder imread_('C:/Users/deniz/OneDrive/Desktop/Bitirme/2.dönem/Program/0 interface.tif'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

There was no problem 1 minute ago.It was reading all the images from any directory.
I did not change anything.

```
filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()

.........there are lots of function.........
print(filename)
while True:
                if vf_iter_counter==0:
                    original = cv.imread(filename)

                image = original.copy()


                k = cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
                if k == 27:
                    break
                cv.resizeWindow('{}'.format(basename1),1920,1080)
                cv.imshow('{}'.format(basename1),image)
```

My main code saved in this directory:

```
C:/Users/deniz/OneDrive/Desktop/Bitirme/2.dönem/Program/xx.png
```

It responses well with different file directory:

```
C:/Users/deniz/OneDrive/Desktop/dersler 2/Mekatronik/xx.png
```

Same response as its own file:

```
C:/Users/deniz/OneDrive/Desktop/Bitirme/2.dönem/Program/xx.png
```

So it has to be read.

The code reads images outside of its own file, but does not work in its own file.

Could it be related with environmental path?
Thx.

Comment: No.  If you are giving `cv.imread()` the correct pathname you enviornment variables will not affect the results.  You must be supplying an incorrect path.

Comment: You are probably using relative paths, so it would work properly in one directory but not the other.  Force all of your path locations to be absolute paths.

Comment: How do ı force path locations. According to your @alexpdev comment `C:/Users/deniz/OneDrive/Desktop/blue_channel.jpg` is relative path when ı try to get absolute path with `abs_path = os.path.abspath(basename1)` it gives `C:\Users\deniz\OneDrive\Desktop\Bitirme\2.dönem\Program\blue_channel.jpg` and does not run. How does the code find the previous folder like this one. Can you state my mistake please?thx

Comment: With the absolute path, when ı select the image on outside of its file or inside it does not run both @alexpdev

Comment: It is like the folder locked itself but does not run the images . At this time ı check the file integrity with  `os.path.exists(filename)` it returns `True`

Comment: known problem. OpenCV has trouble with unusual characters in paths, no matter if absolute or relative. **use relative paths that only contain ascii characters**. this has been asked before. there are answers, workarounds.